# Disable evening shipments

Tags: magento-1.7, shipment, delivery, delivery-date

My webshop ships products every workday and evening except for saturdayevening. The problem is my customers can still click on evening delivery when they choos for a delivery on saturday. I want to disable that feature but I don't know how.
If anyone encountered the same problem please help.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what shipping module you are using, but you can make the modification in the template file directly.

```
 app/design/frontend/yourtheme/default/template/checkout/onepage/shipping_method/available.phtml
```

In there you can simply use the PHP `date` function to restrict the availability of your shipping method

There is obviously much cleaner solutions (like making your own block PHP and doing the logic in the block itself, rather than the template)